# Property Polymorphism With Optional IBOutlet

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, memory-management, properties

I have a polymorphic chain of UITableViewCells in my iOS project (simplified for question):

```
   ====================
  | BaseCellWithButton |
   ====================
            ^
            |
            |
 ========================
| BaseCellWithTwoButtons |
 ========================
```

BaseCellWithButton has 1 property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton* button;
```

BaseCellWithTwoButtons is complex enough that I would like to create a nib. I know that IBOutlet properties are typically `(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet ...`, but I'd like to declare it like `(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet ...` so that I can optionally set it in a child class from a nib, but if not, I can instantiate it in the parent.

Is this a bad practice? Is there a better way to achieve polymorphism, while allowing subclasses to create a nib and still reuse parent attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare `button` as `IBOutlet` in your `BaseCellWithButton` class, and then just connect button from xib in any of your subclasses.

[image]

I attached example files, you can add it to any project, and look how it works.

There are Base and Child class.

Also `strong` reference is best practice if you plan instantiate it via code in parent class

In Base class, there are declared `button` but it connected to xib only in Child class
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48223929/SubclassTableCellsExample.zip

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am aware that I can use parent attributes from child nibs as you've shown. What I am curious about is the right way to declare the attribute in the parent class if it will *optionally* be hooked up to an IBOutlet. Typically, when it is, the attribute should be declared 'weak'. When not, it is necessary to obtain a strong reference to the object and therefore it is declared with a 'strong' attribute.

Comment: You can have a strong reference that is an optional. The strong/weak thing is irrelevant (a weak reference _has_ to be an optional, but that's also irrelevant here)

Comment: Whoops too much swift for me! The point is the same though - the memory management semantics don't affect what you're talking about.

Comment: I don't see a problem with declaring weak or strong reference to IBOutlet - this is depends of you. Xcode create strong references for IBOutlets in some cases (view isn't a subview, but in the same nib)

Answer (score 0):

The only significant difference between declaring your property weak or strong is in the setter which is synthesised for you.  You are accustomed to seeing weak with IBOutlets because they are typically UIView subclasses which are added to some other view.  Adding a view to another puts it in an array (the subviews array belonging to the parent view) and this causes the array to put a retain on the object.

*edit* thanks @nielsBot for the comment, weak pointers are also automatically set to nil for you when an object they were pointing to is released/deallocated, which used to be our problem back when we used assign rather than weak..  So if you were to make an IBOutlet strong then you still need to set that pointer to nil in one of your teardown methods *

consider this

```
@interface someViewController()

@property (weak, nonatomic) UIButton *weakButton1, *weakButton2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *strongButton1;

@end




@implementation someViewController

-(void ) viewDidLoad{

CGRect buttonRect = CGRectMake(20.0, 20.0, 250.0, 40.0 ) ;

self.weakButton1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: buttonRect ];

//the following messages are passed to nil, because the weakButton1 pointer is weak,
// with no other retains the button was nilled out immediately...
// therefore we lose the button we created, it never make it to the view

[self.weakButton1 addTarget:self action: @selector (buttonAction: ) forEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubView: self.weakButton1];

/////////////////////////////////////

self.strongButton1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: buttonRect ];

//this one on the other hand works no problem

[self.strongButton1 addTarget:self action: @selector (buttonAction:) forEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubView: self.strongButton1];

/////////////////////////////

UIButton *tempButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: buttonRect ];

//button created into a scoped (temporary) pointer, which is strong by default, no problem...

[tempButton addTarget:self action: @selector (buttonAction:) forEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubView: tempButton];

//button is assigned to weak property AFTER it is added to view (which causes a retain), no problem
self.weakButton2 = tempButton;

///////////////////////
}
@end
```

Comment: I don't think that's why outlets are generally declared *weak*. It's so you don't have to zero all references to objects you load from a NIB file. (Since those objects have references maintained to them as long as the owner object is live)

Comment: yes, true.  Well if it is not WHY outlets are set to weak then it is HOW is it possible, no? :)